Is there any way to still be able to use brown sugar/butter mixture that has become hard? Probably from overcooking it
I was trying to melt my butter and brown sugar to a caramel sauce, sort of, and it was incorporating so I kept stirring and it has now become rock hard, is there any way to still be able to do so this or do I just chuck it? TIA

Well, it should be edible - you might well have made something similar to a hard caramel.

At what temperature is it "rock hard?" I can say that if you happen to have humid weather, I left some hard caramelized sugar (just the tiniest bt too far caramaleized - not inedible but ever-so-slightly burnt-tasting, so not getting eaten fast; but not bad enough to throw out) sitting out and over the course of a week or so it pulled enough humidity from the air to "sauce" the outside of the lump. So likely you could directly add water (hot, even, with low heat, covered) for a faster result, or just let that happen unless you are in a very dry area.

If it’s too hard, just break it up and then sprinkle it over ice cream or other desserts.  (This is easier to do if you let it cool in a thin sheet; if it’s a lump, it might require a (clean) hammer.)

It sounds like you made it hot enough into the candy stage? So I guess you could try to dissolve it in hot water over time, or you could crush and pulverize it up into a sugar crystal mixture somehow.
